# Set AutoRemove false for running container

Tags: docker

I wanted to add a restart policy to a running container without restarting it via `docker update --restart=always <container-id>` but since I originally started the container with the `--rm` flag (which sets AutoRemove = true) the update fails as you can either set a RestStartPolicy or AutoRemove.

Is there any way to get rid of AutoRemove without stopping and starting the container?

Comment: _Note that if the container is started with “--rm” flag, you cannot update the restart policy for it. The `AutoRemove` and `RestartPolicy` are mutually exclusive for the container._
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/#update-a-containers-restart-policy. So the answer seems to be: no.

Comment: The question was how to get rid of the AutoRemove flag. I guess that the author is aware of that the options are mutally exclusive (*since I originally started the container with the --rm flag (which sets AutoRemove = true) the update fails* ..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot get rid of the AutoRemove flag, docker does not support changing that, because the docker daemon starts monitoring a container with `--rm` the moment it's started (to perform the removal). According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40852), that would be difficult to implement.

Comment: Thank you so much for finding this github issue! This is really helpful